# HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP with Tomcat 9.0

Tags: database, jsp

Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M1

THIS IS MY PROGRAM ::::::::::::::::::::

```
 <table border=27>

    <%@ page import="java.sql.*;"%>

    <%!
        Connection con;

        Statement st;

        public void jspInit()

        {
            try

              {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","shah");

                st=con.createStatement();                
               }

              catch(Exception e)

              {
                System.err.println(e);
              }
        }
     %>

     <%
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select *from student");

        ResultSetMetaData rm=rs.getMetaData();

            int n=rm.getColumnCount();

            out.println("<tr>");

            for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)

            {
                out.println("<th>"+rm.getColumnName(i)+"</th>");
            }

            out.println("</tr>");

            while(rs.next())

            {
                out.println("<tr>");

                for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)

                {
                    out.println("<td>"+rs.getString(i)+"</td>");
                }

                out.println("</tr>");
            }

     %>

    <%!
        public void destroy()

        {
            try
              {
                con.close();
              }
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                System.err.println(e);
              }
        }


    %>

    </tr>
</table>    
</body>
```

HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Comment: what is the meaning of `<%!`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*;" %>
```

that `;` in import is not valid in a jsp .if you want to import more then one package seperate them with `,`.

ex:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*,java.io.*" %>
```